# change thumbnail image for main image

Tags: javascript, html

do i have a syntax error? , could it be that im using notepad++?
 nothing is happening when i click a thumbnail image
i am new to javascript so that may be the case.
my general idea was to create an event "changeimage" that onclick would change the source of my main image for my thumbnails image to make it bigger.

```
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function changeimage(event) 
  {
    event = event;

    var targetElement = event.target;

    if (targetElement.tagName == "IMG")
    { 
    document.getElementbyid("Main").src = targetelement.getattribute("src"); 
    } 
  } 
    </script>
 <meta charset="utf=8">
<style>
#Main
{
height:540px; 
width:540px;
}
.imgthmb1
{
height:100px;
width:100px;
}
</style>
</head>

  <body>
  <img id="Main" src="img/rickroll1.jpg" </img>
   <br />
    <div id="thumbnail" onclick="changeimage(event)">
    <img class="imgthmb1" src="img/rickroll1.jpg" />
    <img class="imgthmb1" src="img/rickroll2.jpg" />
    <img class="imgthmb1" src="img/rickroll3.jpg" />
    <img class="imgthmb1" src="img/rickroll4.jpg" />
    <img class="imgthmb1" src="img/rickroll5.jpg" />
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by sending event as parameter?

Comment: This is incorrect: `<img id="Main" src="img/rickroll1.jpg" </img>`. it should be `<img id="Main" src="img/rickroll1.jpg" />`

Comment: change document.getElementbyid("Main").src = targetelement.getattribute("src"); to document.getElementbyid("Main").src = targetElement.getattribute("src");

Comment: when you setting the src attr you are not refrencing the targetElement correctly. You spelled as targetelement instead of targetElement. Just capitlize the E in element and it should work

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have a syntax  error:

`targetElement` is spelled `targetelement` in the following line:

> ```
> document.getElementbyid("Main").src = targetelement.getattribute("src");
> ```

Change it to the following:

```
document.getElementbyid("Main").src = targetElement.getattribute("src");
```

On a related note, the following line is extraneous and can be removed:

> ```
> event = event;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case-sensitive.

in place of

```
document.getElementbyid("Main").src = targetelement.getattribute("src");
```

write

```
document.getElementbyId("Main").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
```

Also your html markup has an error:

```
<img id="Main" src="img/rickroll1.jpg" </img>
```

should be

```
<img id="Main" src="img/rickroll1.jpg">
```